# Java 8 - working with JsonObject (javax.json) - how to determine if a node has child nodes?

Tags: java, json, java-8

I've just started using javax.json package. I know how to extract values from JSON object in Java 8 if I know the structure of my JSON string. But how about strings I don't know the structure of? The question: how to determine if a node has child nodes?

To read values, I simply need to use "get*" methods - it works OK, but there's no method like "checkIfArray" or "checkIfObject" to check if I even can use methods like "getString"...

Comment: How about `JsonStructure::isEmpty`?

Comment: `JsonObject results = obj.getJsonObject("query");
System.out.println(results.getJsonObject("lang").isEmpty());` This code will check if the 'lang' node is empty, but only if it is empty or if it has child nodes. If the 'lang' node is a string, it will throw an exception, so I don't have any other way to check if the 'lang' node is array or object? Do I need to use exceptions to check that?

Comment: Of course not. Every type in `javax.json` is-a `java.util.Map<String, JsonValue>`. You can simply call `get` on it, and if what's returned is not a `null`, then you can match against calling for `JsonValue::getValueType`.

Comment: Correction: `JsonObject` is-a `Map` only, `JsonArray` is-a `java.util.List<JsonValue>`. Rest is the same, effectively, down to `isEmpty()` on both of these types.

Comment: Seems that you cleared the situation for me, I don't have any questions for now. Thanks :)

Comment: I'll fashion that into an answer then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `javax.json` package, both available types support emptiness checks because they both implement a `java.collection` interfaces:

`JsonObject` is-a `java.util.Map<String, JsonValue>`. As a result, one can check if such object contains any values by simply calling `isEmpty()` method.

`JsonArray` is-a `java.util.List<JsonValue>`. As a result, one - again - can check if the array is empty by calling `isEmpty()` method on it.

For traversing a tree of `JsonStructure`s while marking all empty nodes, you can use this helper method:

```
boolean isValueEmpty(JsonValue v) {
  if (v == null) {
    return true; // or you may throw an exception, for example
  }
  switch(v.getValueType()) {
    case NULL:
      return true; // same as with Java null, we assume that it is Empty
    case ARRAY: 
      return ((JsonArray) v).isEmpty();
      // additionally, you can say that empty array is array with only empty elements
      // this means a check like this:
      // return ((JsonArray v).stream().allMatch(isValueEmpty); // recurse
    case OBJECT:
      return ((JsonObject v).isEmpty();
    case STRING:
      // optionally: if you want to treat '' as empty
      return ((JsonString v).getString().isEmpty();
    default:
      return false; // to my knowledge, no other Json types can be empty
  }
}
```